# Trying to update properties if it exists using gremlin query I am getting error as "Cannot find name 'has'"

Tags: node.js, amazon-neptune, gremlin-server

Trying to update properties if it exists using gremlin query I am getting error as `Cannot find name 'has'` and the same query runs fine in Neptune notebook. But for the same thing in node.js I am getting error at "has"

Below is the query. What am I missing here?
`Graph.V(Id).hasLabel('test').optional(has('nameProperty').property(single,'nameProperty', 'value'))`

Answer (score 0):

When called from code "anonymous" traversals - parts of a query not connected to others by a dot, may need to be prefixed with `__.` as below:

```
Graph.V(Id).
   hasLabel('test').
   optional(__.has('nameProperty').
      property(single,'nameProperty', 'value'))
```

The `__.` is actually a special class that TinkerPop defines for cases such as this one. Note that in many languages like Java and Python it is possible to statically include/import this class so that you do not actually have to use the `__.` syntax unless you encounter a reserved word collision with the language such as `not` in Groovy.

Comment: I have updated it like below still I am getting same error                                                    `const __ = gremlin.process.statics;                                                                                                            
        Graph.V(Id). hasLabel('test').optional(__.has('nameProperty').property(single,'nameProperty', 'value'))`

Comment: I did a test just now using the 3.4.10 Gremlin JavaScript client and Node.js and had no problems. I am not sure what may be happening in your environment.

Comment: In case it helps these are the imports I used in my test: `const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const Graph = gremlin.structure.Graph;
const __ = gremlin.process.statics;
const { t,order,cardinality,column,scope,pop,operator,P,traversal } = gremlin.process;
`